# Matching strings with wildcards in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have some IP addresses:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.*
200.*
```

How can I simply match a given IP address against these ranges quickly and easily.  There could potentially be thousands of patterns such as the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save you from pain, you should use [CIDR addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) instead of your string wildcards. This is the generally accepted notation for networks and sane ranges of IPs. You will find a wide support for this notation in about any language.

In your case, the networks would be

```
127.0.0.1/32 (or just simply 127.0.0.1)
192.168.0.0/16
200.0.0.0/8
```

The you can use something like the built-in `IPAddr` class or the [IPAddress gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ipaddress) to parse those.

With the IPAddress gem, you can then do something like this (untested):

```
range = IPAddress("192.168.0.0/16")
ip = IPAddress("192.168.3.5")
range.include? ip # returns true
```

Comment: This works identical with [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F) from stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

Following should match,

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```